# how to define type when the component is a union type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a case：https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-herschel-9lvmb?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const A: React.FC<{ a: string }> = ({ a }) => {
  return <div>{a}</div>;
};

const B: React.FC<{ a: string; c: number }> = ({ a, c }) => {
  return <div>{a + c}</div>;
};

const switchFunc = (num: number) => {
  // Maybe there are lots of cases with different returns(different components)
  if (num > 0.5) {
    return A;
  } else {
    return B;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const condition = Math.random();

  const renderContent = (props: { a: string } | { a: string; c: number }) => {
    const Component = switchFunc(condition);

    return (
      <div>
        {/** omit other content */}
        {/** here type error!!! */}
        <Component {...props} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderContent(condition > 0.5 ? { a: "hello" } : { a: "hi", c: 1 })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I got a type error when using `<Component />`, so how should I define types in this case?

I can't know the component type that the `switchFunc` returns. (In actual use, maybe lots of cases), so it keeps a union type but the `props` is intersection type.

thanks

Comment: So you are checking `condition > 0.5` in the App return and also check again in `switchFunc`? You should read conditional rendering in React doc https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. And also, a little tip, give meaningful names to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `A`'s props to be of type `{ a: string }`, while you might pass it props of type `{ a: string; c: number }` (and vice versa with `B`).

In order to keep consistency, I'd define the type of props separately, then use it as the props type for both `A` and `B`:

```
type MyProps = { a: string } | { a: string, c: number };

const A: React.FC<MyProps> = (props: MyProps) => {
  const { a } = props; 
  return <div>{a}</div>;
};

const B: React.FC<MyProps> = (props: MyProps) => {
  const { a, c } = props;
  return <div>{a + c}</div>;
};
```

(With that being said, I agree with **@Dilshan** that this isn't an ideal pattern nor ideal variables' names)